# How do I use One login screen activity for different activities in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

i'm currently developing an Android app in Android Studio and i'm trying to use only one login screen for two different screens instead of using two login screens which will use the phone memory more. 
I tried using if and else statements where if button 1 was clicked then send to screen 1. 
Below is my code:

```
public void userLogin() {

    String userEmail = email.getText().toString();
    String userPass = password.getText().toString();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(userEmail)){
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please Enter Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(userPass)){
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please Enter Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPass)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        finish();
                        if (mainactivity.type == 1) {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, EmployeeActivity.class));
                        }
                        if(mainactivity.type == 2){
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AdminActivity.class));
                        }
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "ERROR: Invalid Email or Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    }

                });
            }
```

Crash Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.javytharanee.quicksolattendance, PID: 7078
              android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent {  }
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2007)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1673)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4586)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:767)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4544)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:754)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4905)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4873)
                  at com.javytharanee.quicksolattendance.LoginActivity$2$override.onComplete(LoginActivity.java:89)
                  at com.javytharanee.quicksolattendance.LoginActivity$2$override.access$dispatch(Unknown Source:86)
                  at com.javytharanee.quicksolattendance.LoginActivity$2.onComplete(LoginActivity.java:77)
                  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(Unknown Source:23)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Any help would be much appreciated as i'm totally new to app development.

Comment: And what exactly is wrong with this code?

Comment: The app crashes whenever i login, or if i edit some code it would send me to only 1 screen even if i click button 2

Comment: Well, what does it say when it crashes? Whats the log.

Comment: In that case you need to include the crashlog here. Without that we won't be able to help you.

Comment: show us the crash error reporting in log windows

Comment: Alright i'll update my question

Comment: I tried reproducing the error but its now sending me back to the Main Activity instead of crashing

Comment: Are your activities defined in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Yes they are in the file

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `finish()` after `startActivity()`. You are losing context to your activity hence `LoginActivity.this` is return null.

Like this

```
if(mainactivity.type == 1){
   Toast.makeToast(LoginActivity.this, "Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
   startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, EmployeeActivity.class));
}

if(mainactivity.type == 2){
   Toast.makeToast(LoginActivity.this, "Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
   startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, 
   Employee2Activity.class));
}

LoginActivity.this.finish();
```

Answer (score -1):

public void userLogin() {

```
    String userEmail = email.getText().toString();
    String userPass = password.getText().toString();
    Log.e(TAG, "userLogin: "+userEmail  +userPass );
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userEmail)) {
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please Enter Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userPass)) {
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please Enter Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "userLogin: " );
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPass)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Log.e(TAG, "onComplete: "+mainactivity.type );
                            if (mainactivity.type == 1) {
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, EmployeeActivity.class));
                                finish();
                            } else if (mainactivity.type == 2) {
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AdminActivity.class));
                                finish();
                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "ERROR: Invalid Email or Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }

                });
    }
}
```

Comment: i have edited your code . your logic was a little wrong .  try to understand my if else statements

Comment: It stays on the login screen now, it doesn't go to the other activities

Comment: No i want to go to different screens not back

Comment: No there's a main activity wheres there's two buttons and when you click on 1 of them you go to the login screen, and when you login it goes to another screen

Comment: D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
               Notified 0 auth state listeners.

This is what i get

Comment: How can i send it?

Comment: copy paste in comment

Comment: When i add the TAG line it says it has private access

Comment: Log.e("", "userLogin: "+userEmail  +userPass );  remove tag and write "" like this in all logs

Comment: Still stays on the login screen

Comment: run and give me log cat screen shot

Comment: so i can see what the value of type is coming